# Get domain from URL to GROUP BY using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table filled with URLs. The URLs are in all sorts of formats: http://foo.com, http://bar.foo.com, http://foo.com/bar, etc. But I'm only interested in the domain name itself, so in this case: foo.com. What I'd like to do is select how many times domain names exists in this table. So something like:

```
SELECT "whatever the domain is in field 'url'", COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table_with_urls
GROUP BY "whatever the domain is in field 'url'"
```

There are a few similar questions on Stack Overflow, but nothing really answered this. I can't use LIKE or match something with REGEXP, because I'm not (always) looking for specific domain names to match against, but mostly I just want *all* domain names from the table along with a total count.

Is this possible using MySQL?

Comment: It's very difficult to define 'domain name' as you have things like 'foo.co.uk', 'mydomain.myhost.com', 'foo.museum', etc. The only accurate way to do it is to have a list of the possible top level domains, and that list is quite long (100s of elements). Can you be more specific by what you mean by 'domain name' in your context?

Comment: Looking for only 2 in 1:[subdomain]2:[foo.com/foo.co.uk]3:[/whatever]. But I was afraid that it would come to something as matching against all possible TLDs and such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add another indexed column for 'domain' and when you do an INSERT, store this value separately.

Answer (score 10):

i had the same problem and this is what i did:

```
select SUBSTRING(url from 1 for locate('/',url ,10)-1),count(*) from url_list group by SUBSTRING(url from 1 for locate('/',url ,10)-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a MySQL extension then https://github.com/StirlingMarketingGroup/mysql-get-etld-p1

It extracts basically what you'd expect it to

```
select`get_etld_p1`('http://a.very.complex-domain.co.uk:8080/foo/bar');-- 'complex-domain.co.uk'
select`get_etld_p1`('https://www.bbc.co.uk/');-- 'bbc.co.uk'
select`get_etld_p1`('https://github.com/StirlingMarketingGroup/');-- 'github.com'
select`get_etld_p1`('https://localhost:10000/index');-- 'localhost'
select`get_etld_p1`('android-app://com.google.android.gm');-- 'com.google.android.gm'
select`get_etld_p1`('example.test.domain.com');-- 'domain.com'
select`get_etld_p1`('postgres://user:pass@host.com:5432/path?k=v#f');-- 'host.com'
select`get_etld_p1`('exzvk.omsk.so-ups.ru');-- 'so-ups.ru'
select`get_etld_p1`('http://10.64.3.5/data_check/index.php?r=index/rawdatacheck');-- '10.64.3.5'
select`get_etld_p1`('not a domain');-- null
```

Then, if you wanted that to be performant, you could make a second, denormalizing, column that stores just those values, something like

```
CREATE TABLE `db`.`sometablewithurls` (
  `SomeTableWithURLsID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `URL` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `_ETLDP1` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`SomeTableWithURLsID`),
  INDEX `_ETLDP1` (`_ETLDP1` ASC));
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `db`.`sometablewithurls_BEFORE_INSERT`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `db`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `db`.`sometablewithurls_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `sometablewithurls` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

set new.`_ETLDP1`=ifnull(`get_etld_p1`(new.`URL`),'');

END$$
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `db`.`sometablewithurls_BEFORE_UPDATE`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `db`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `db`.`sometablewithurls_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `sometablewithurls` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

set new.`_ETLDP1`=ifnull(`get_etld_p1`(new.`URL`),'');

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Notice the index on the `_ETLDP1` (stands for extended top-level domain plus 1), and the trigger updating it both on insert *and* on update to make sure it keeps up to date even if URL changes.